# This.state brings undefined and next the object

Tags: reactjs, fetch, console.log

When I'm doing a fetch for the details of an instrument, fetch give me first the state with undefined status and in the next line the object. Making that the props in first place read the undefined information and breaking the page.

```
class Detailinstrumentos extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        instrumentos: [],
    }
};

async componentDidMount(){
    try{
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;

        // console.log("id",this.props)
        
        let instrumentos = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/instrumentos/${id}`).then(response => response.json())
        
            // console.log(instrumentos)

        this.setState({
            // id: id,
            instrumentoDetail: instrumentos.id
            
        });
        
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
render(){
        let instrumento1 = this.state.instrumentoDetail
        console.log("holaaaa",instrumento1)
        return(
            <article className="instrumentos-article">    
            <Instrumento
                                         imagenes={instrumento1.imagenes[0].url_imagen}
                                         nombre={instrumento1.nombre}
                                         fabricante={instrumento1.fabricante}
                                         precio={instrumento1.precio}
                                        />
        </article>
    )
```

}

This appear when i havent commented the props

```
detailInstrumentos.js:36 holaaaa undefined
detailInstrumentos.js:36 holaaaa undefined

detailInstrumentos.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 
'imagenes')
at Detailinstrumentos.render (detailInstrumentos.js:40:1)
at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17485:1)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17435:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
render @ detailInstrumentos.js:40
finishClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17485
updateClassComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17435
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19073
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26020
render @ react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js @ index.js:9
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
```

And this appear when i had commented the props

```
detailInstrumentos.js:36 holaaaa undefined
detailInstrumentos.js:36 holaaaa {id: 2, nombre: 'Bajo-Eléctrico-4-Cuerdas-Newen-Onas-Jb', 
fabricante: 'Newen-Onas', precio: 120000, descuento: 0, …}
```

So my question is. Why the console.log is sending me 2 times the log, one time undefined and next the object?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you the fetch request is not made at first `componentDidMount` runs after the first render on the screen to avoid this use `componentWillMount`  instead

and the reason you are getting that long error is because you saved only the Id and you are trying to call other object

Comment: I tryed with componenWillMount but it says is not recommend it. And yeah the idea of the id its that brings the object that match with that id, so it brings all the instrument object, but what i was asking is why the console.log gives me 2 answers, the undefined one and the object, because its bring in good the information, but next the undefined

Answer (score 0):

because `render` method is called first and then `componentDidMount`.
first time that render method is called, there is no `instrumentoDetail` in state object of component and console prints `undefined`. after calling render, `componentDidMount` gets called and using `setState()` inside of it causes re render component. in second render `instrumentoDetail` is in state object of component so console prints it.
see https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: And how would you fix it? Because i tryed with UNSAFE_componentWillMount() and the same thing happended

Comment: I don't know exactly, perhaps it is unavoidable. if you go to above link you see that React documentation says: You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state.  it often causes performance issues.. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.